# how to work java cipher aes-cbc

Tags: java, encryption, aes

I work with cipher `AES-cbc`. I have a thrid part string encrypted and a key.

I would like to ask some questions,

When I decrypted I got the exception

```
javax.crypto.BadPaddingException: Given final block not properly padded
  at com.sun.crypto.provider.SunJCE_f.b(DashoA13*..)
  at com.sun.crypto.provider.SunJCE_f.b(DashoA13*..)
  at com.sun.crypto.provider.AESCipher.engineDoFinal(DashoA13*..)
```

I read in the forums that this can be because the encrypt key and the decrypt key are differents. Can this happen in my problem?.

Also how I work with cbc I neeed a iv vector. But I don't know the iv vector encrypted. Do I need this vector?. How can I get I?

Comment: Consider accepting answers that are helpful. 

To accept an answer click on the hollow checkmark next to the answer that is best, doing so will increase your reputation and allow more capabilities, See [reputation faq](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#reputation)  See [this page](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) for more detail.

Also please consider going back and accepting past answers, doing so will increase your reputation and allow more capabilities, See [reputation faq](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#reputation)

Answer (score 0):

CBC stands for Cipher Block Chaining which means that the output from encrypting one block of data is XORed with the next input block. For the first block a random block of data (called an IV) is XORed with the input instead. The IV should just be random data and is generated when the encryption is performed. You definitely do need the IV and there is no way to recover it. You can only get it from whoever generated it. Not having the correct IV is almost certainly the cause of your padding exception.

Comment: The IV is only a cause of the exception if the message is only a single block long. A wrong IV has only influence on the first block.

Comment: Ah true. I was thinking of encryption but for decryption you are right of course.

Answer (score 0):

Padding errors generally mean that the decryption failed but can not be relied on to determine correct decryption and if reported to a caller can create a padding oracle which can be used to recover the original text without the key. This can be because the padding method, mode, key or iv is not the same for encryption and decryption.

It is best if the key and iv exactly match the requirements, the iv length is the same as the block which for AES is 16-bytes. The key can be 128-bits (16-bytes), 192-bits (24-bytes) or 256-bits (32-bytes).

For CBC mode an iv is needed and the best practice is to generate a random iv and prepend it to the encrypted data, that allows the decryption to have the same iv available. The iv does not need to be secret.